# NSManagedObject loop returns duplicates Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, for-loop, core-data

I'm trying to append the NSManagedObject array while saving the core data context.
To do so i'm using the following code

```
func startme(){

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let forquestions = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Questions", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let abc = NSManagedObject(entity: forquestions!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    for lines in linesmain["start"]! {
        abc.setValue(lines, forKey:"question")
        myDataArray.append([abc])
    }

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("Could not save \(error)") }
    }
```

unfortunately instead of getting three different objects inside myDataArray - i'm just getting three duplicates like these

> [[ (entity: Questions; id:
>   0x7f8761dac300
>    ;
>   data: {
>       question = "hi I'm row 1"; })],
>  [ (entity: Questions; id: 0x7f8761dac300
>    ;
>   data: {
>       question = "hi I'm row 1"; })],
>  [ (entity: Questions; id: 0x7f8761dac300
>    ;
>   data: {
>       question = "hi I'm row 1"; })]]

when i try to add `print(myDataArray)` inside the loop - it prints three various objects which is perfectly fine.

I have no idea why the for loop doesn't work well for NSManagedObject array.
Looking forward to your insights.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating only one NSManaged Object, with this line:

```
let abc = NSManagedObject(entity: forquestions!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
```

Your for loop then sets one of its attributes and appends it to your array.  Each time through, the loop it is acting on exactly the same NSManagedObject.   Not a copy.  So the same object ends up in your array 3 times.  When you println at the end, all three elements are identical: same id and same `question`.  If you println within the for loop, the ids should all be the same, but each iteration should show the "current" value for `question`.  If you want three different NSManagedObjects, just move the above line inside the for loop.  A new, different NSManagedObject will be created and added each time through the loop.

One other point to note: you are appending `[abc]`, which is an array containing the NSManagedObject, not the NSManagedObject itself.  So `myDataArray` ends up as an array of arrays of NSManagedObjects.  I suspect you actually want:

```
    myDataArray.append(abc)
```